# Is this a allowed way to write a method JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, methods

I made a mistake with writing the methods. But it still works and is way shorter is it allowed to write it like this?

```
var Mark = {
  firstName: 'Mark',
  lastName: 'Wielstra',
  mass: 78,
  height: 1.69,
  calculateBMI() {
    this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    return this.bmi;
  }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
var Mark = {
  firstName: 'Mark',
  lastName: 'Wielstra',
  mass: 78,
  height: 1.69,
  calculateBMI: function() {
    this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    return this.bmi;
  }
}
```

Comment: afaik, javascript tends to parse whatever anyway! A better question would be "in what scenario will this code crash"

Answer (score 0):

This is (somewhat new) syntax [introduced in EcmaScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

> Given the following code:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   foo: function() {
>     /* code */
>   },
>   bar: function() {
>     /* code */
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> You are now able to shorten this to:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   foo() {
>     /* code */
>   },
>   bar() {
>     /* code */
>   }
> };
> ```

So yes, it is allowed and equivalent to the old (more verbose) syntax.